# In visual studio do you know what the name of this control?

Tags: c#-2.0

you see images attached to this control. do you know what the name of this control ? Have DevExpress got this control ? [IMG]http://imagizer.imageshack.com/img673/6260/TV6dOt.jpg[/IMG]

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, this can be easily achieved with the basic WPF grid system. First row is a header, the separation line is just a row which span all columns.

Comment: Have you got examples XtraGrid or visual studio? share me with

Comment: @user3577283 Grid is the most basic thing in WPF. You can find tons of examples online. not sure about what XtraGrid is